# Animation of images for muti-selected images from photo library of an ipad

Tags: image, animation, slider, uiimagepickercontroller, photolibrary

There are two components of this apps as entilted.

1) Multi selection of  images from photo library:

reference -
    http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HyU7zNzwcrI&feature=BFa&list=HL1350876847,
    http://www.icodeblog.com/2010/10/07/cloning-uiimagepickercontroller-using-the-assets-
    library-framework/

2) Animation of images :

```
reference -
http://www.garrahan.org/src/SonicSpeed.zip
```

---

I would like to combine these two components into one apps,
i.e. When using this apps, I could select multi images from photo library of ipad,
     and then animation of images would result with a user-defined speed.

I suspect the chosen images of photo library by user are from "NSDictionary * dict" of the first component ( (1) Multi selection of  images from photo library. )

Could anyone please help?
Many thanks!